# How can I save data from Shiny into MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I try to make a simple app, which shows data from mySQL table and helps users to save new data in it.
I already connect DB and read the table.

The problems begins when I save data from shiny input. Ive tried a lot of different cases and it didn`t helps for me.
The main aim is to add new row in table in MySQL after user clicked on "Add user", and update table with new data in UI.

Its simplified  version of my app:

```
library(DBI)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Enter your name:"),
  numericInput("age", "How ald are you?", ""),
  submitButton("save", "Add user"),
  br(),
  tableOutput("tbl"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  getDataSql <- function(query) {
    con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname  =  "database", host = "host", user = "root", password = "password", port = 3306)
    result <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
    dbDisconnect(con)
    result
  }

  saveDataSql <- function(query) {
    con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname  =  "database", host = "host", user = "root", password = "password", port = 3306)
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
    dbDisconnect(con)
  }

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    query <- "SELECT * FROM test;"
    getDataSql(query)
  })

  observe({
    if (input$save > 0){
      query <- sprintf<-(paste("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `age`) VALUES ('", input$name, " ','", input$age, "');", sep = ""))
      saveDataSql(query)

    }
    return()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPD**
I update part of my code using *dbExecute* but it still doesnt work.

```
observeEvent(input$save, { con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
        dbname = "stocktheft", host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", 
        password = "123456", port = 3306) 
query <- paste("INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('", input$name, " ','", input$age, "');", sep = "") 
dbExecute(con, query) 
dbDisconnect(con) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started with `SQL` and `DBI`, so I may be wrong, but have you tried using `dbExecute(query)` to execute the `INSERT` sql command? 
Your `saveDataSql` is using `dbGetQuery` to retrieve data, rather than actually execute the `INSERT`.

For example, if I want to add an index I usually do

```
SQLcommand <- "CREATE INDEX indxName ON myTable (myColumn)"
dbExecute(myDB,SQLcommand)
```

**update**

You may also want to check the use of a `submitButton`. You are saving to the database when `input$save > 0`, which is never happening as they don't have a value. I would do something on the line

```
# ui
actionButton("save", "Add user")

# server
observeEvent(input$save,{
    query <- sprintf<-(paste("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `age`) VALUES ('", input$name, " ','", input$age, "');", sep = ""))
    saveDataSql(query)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I rewrite my code using dbExecute and now Im sure that you are right. But it still don`t work.

Comment: try with `if (input$save)`. `submitButton` does not have a value per se, but simply force all input to send their values to the server. it will never be `>0`. I would replace that with an `actionButton` and then use and `observeEvent` in the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just change **submitButton** on **actionButton** and it works.